# Detect and Remove Multicollinearity in a high-dimensional time-series

Tags: matlab, pca

I am working with a matrix of data, in matlab, with dimensions n-by-m where ('n' are the number of regressors = 61) and ('m' is the number of datapoints = 500). I have reasons to suspect that the data is highly collinear. I have been reading in the topic of 'Collinearity'  and I come to realize that there are many valid options that can be used (e.g. Principal Component analysis).

Starting by the simplest approach, I tried to implement PCA. However, what PCA gives me is the following output: Principal Components, Latent Variables, POV (Percentage of Variance). I basicly creat the principal component space for my data

My question is the following, How can I, after obtaining the principal component space,  convert the variables that I have (PC, Lat, POV) into the time space constraint to the relevent components (typical those that explain 99% of the variance)? In other words, how can my data reflect the PCA analysis?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: No idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 
I am simply asking, how can I use PCA to remove the collinearity among my datachannels (eeg dataset)? After using princomp in matlab the output I get is he one I mentioned ( _Principal Components_, _Latent Variables_, _POV (Percentage of Variance)_) and my question will be how can I use that information to **remove the collinearity** on my data?

Many thanks in advance
@knedlsepp

Comment: What does *removing collinearity* even mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Ok. So you basically want to project your 500 points lying in `R^61` onto a linear subspace?

Comment: To start, I am very new in the field of collinearity, and from what I've been reading remove collinearity means, build a new set of variables that they will not shate a substancial amounts of information between them.

Comment: So in a simple, let's say I have 5 channels of eeg (electroencephalography) data, because they represent only one brain dipole all five channels will be conditioned by the same source. Now what I want, is to find a way to only use information that is non collinear (select the principal component of the data through PCA) but stil have the spatial enconded of the 5 different channel positions.
So first I think I need to perform PCA, am I right? However, afterwards (after getting the Principal components and the latent variables) how can I build the linear subspace that you mentioned? @knedlsepp